# Developing Android games with C# and Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I’ve been learning C# for some time now and I am starting to feel confident. I want to develop mobile games for Android but I don’t know where to start. Can Unity be used for that purpose or are there any other engines that are better suited for Android game development. Also, are there any tutorials on the topic?Because I couldn't find any.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `are there any tutorials on the topic Because I couldn't find any` Here are some **step by step** tutorials from their official site so you can start developing (http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Unity3D is currently the most popular game engine for Android. Considering that they recently release a new license, the full engine is available for free. You can publish your games for Android paying nothing.

And you don't need a specific tutorial for Android. It's everything the same (obviously not the input though), you just have to select Android platform when you want to build and that is it.